# Obtener nombres de los archivos en un directorio con JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp

Tengo un sistema Web en el cual tengo una carpeta con archivos y lo que estoy intentando es traer los nombres de los archivos dentro de esa carpeta.

Mando a llamar un JSP desde `JS` :

```
getUrlJsonObject({
  href:pathcamp+'getNamesDocs.jsp',
  method:"GET",  
},
function(data){}
```

este es el `JSP`

```
<%
    final File folder = new File("/docs");
    for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
        if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
            listFilesForFolder(fileEntry);
        } else {
            System.out.println(fileEntry.getName());
        }
    }
    listFilesForFolder(folder);
%>
```

Pero me arroja el siguiente error:

```
An error occurred at line: 2 in the jsp file: getNamesDocs.jsp
File cannot be resolved to a type
1: <%
2:  final File folder = new File("/docs");
3:  for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
4:      if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
5:  

    listFilesForFolder(fileEntry);
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si ese es el contenido completo de tu fichero JSP, te faltaría importar la clase que contiene el tipo `File`. Para importarla debes incluir esta línea al principio de tu fichero .jsp:

```
import java.io.File;
```

Comment: Hice unas modificaciones, pero ahora no se como devolver esa información al Ajax

Comment: @AlejandroGonzalez Así no es cómo funciona Stack Overflow. Si tienes una nueva pregunta, debes crear una nueva publicación en lugar de modificar totalmente la pregunta existente, dejando las respuestas sin sentido.